# piping input into a .cpp in shell script

Tags: c++, bash, shell

So I am trying to compile then run c++ with piped input in a shell script.  I have to grade 113 programming assignments and I don't want to compile and then run test cases individually.
Code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "the script starts now."
g++ Q2.cpp -o q2
./q2 < ~/scripts/t12.txt
./q2 < ~/scripts/t13.txt
```

Then I get the error: 
'No such file or directoryt.sh: line 4: /home/stevenm/scripts/t12.txt'
and 
'No such file or directoryt.sh: line 5: /home/stevenm/scripts/t13.txt'

but this will work when I run it myself in the command line.

Comment: For debugging purposes, add `ls ~/scripts/t*txt` after the g++. Do these fles exist?

Comment: If your bash tells you that there is no file, then there is no file at the Location. This is not related to the programming languages at all.

Comment: Notice the error message, where `No such file or directory` appears to be overrwriting the name of your script; your script has DOS line endings.